# Программа "стоит" во время ожидания ответа на запрос

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, requests

Я пишу приложение с использованием PyQt5 и во время отправки запросов (`Requests.get()` и `Requests.post()`) через библиотеку `Requests` программа останавливается, пока не придёт ответ от сайта.

Можно как-нибудь избавиться от ожидания ответа? Использование потоков нежелательно.

Comment: Пробовали что-то искать? Почему использование потоков нежелательно?

Comment: Искать пробовал, но ничего полезного не нашёл. С потоками выходит слишком много возьни. Если не найдётся способа поудобнее, то сделаю через потоки.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9110593/13970074

Comment: Если не желаете использовать потоки, тогда ждите. Если в вашем приложении есть действия, которые замораживают интерфейс - вам ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО нужен дополнительный поток!

Comment: @S.Nick доп поток не нужен, можно асинхронно отработать

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что Вам важно отправить запрос, а ответ на него Вам не нужен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не блокировать интерфейс есть несколько способов

Используйте QNetworkAccessManager для запросов - это стандартный интерфейс qt

Используйте потоки, но там проблема с передачей ответа обратно. Нельзя вызывать методы формы из не основного потока.

Можно прикрутить asincio через адаптер и использовать aiohttp клиента на основном цикле qt.